# Is it possible to set different payment gateway on each Gravity Forms form?

Tags: plugins, forms, plugin-gravity-forms

I run a Wordpress site in Australia involving credit card payments. I've been using eWay payment gateway for a while, now I want to introduce Stripe as well to my forms. I have multiple products, each of them has its own form, and I want to be able to control which payment gateway to use for each form.

Example:

1. Product A --> Form A --> use eWay payment gateway
2. Product B --> Form B --> use Stripe

Is this possible? If not, what are my options? Is there a better plugin for this kind of case? Should I modify the internals of the plugin? For the record I am a final year CS major and have an intermediate knowledge of PHP code, so any advanced tricks hopefully would not overwhelm me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, no code modification needed. Simply create an eWay feed (looks like it's only available in their Pro version) for the form you want to process with eWay, and set a Stripe feed for the form you want to process with Stripe.